# how to redefine the citation commands in multibib to include files that use natbib commands

Tags: bibtex, natbib, multibib

I need to create a document with two parts, each having their own bibliography for which I can use *multibib*. However the contents of the two parts should be read in from existing files without changing those. Is there a way to redefine the citation commands such that the files can be included as they are (without replacing all `\citep` with `\citepfirst` and so on)?

Here's a MWE: I want to be able to keep using `citep`, `citealp`, `citet` in each section, but before the section redefine the commands to go into the individual reference section.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myrefs.bib}
@Book{Knuth:1990,
    author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    title     = {The {\TeX}book},
    year      = {1990},
    isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}

@Book{Lamport:94,
    author    = {Lamport, Leslie},
    title     = {{\LaTeX}: A Document Preparation System},
    year      = {1994},
    isbn      = {0-021-52983-1},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{first}{First refs}

% store the original cite commands
\let\citeporig\citep
\let\citealporig\citealp
\let\citetorig\citet

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

% let all the cite commands use the first bibliography
\let\citep\citepfirst
\let\citealp\citealpfirst
\let\citet\citetfirst

Refer to Lamport \citep[e.g.][]{Lamport:94}.

\bibliographystylefirst{plainnat}
\bibliographyfirst{myrefs}

\section{Second section}

% redefine the commands to use the second bibliography
\let\citep\citeporig
\let\citealp\citealporig
\let\citet\citetorig

The ultimate reference~\cite{Knuth:1990}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{myrefs}


\end{document}
```